# How to center image in the very center of container (Bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a team section for a website. It is supposed to have 4 columns (for 4 team members) and below the columns there will be a short text. Then when I click on a photo of the team member a modal will open and give additional description.

Everything works fine so far, but the images of team members are not positioned in the center. For some reason I cannot position them using text-center or center-block classes (I am using Bootstrap 3). And this is really important because website is responsive so it doesn't look good if the person on the photo is only 'half' visible in some resolutions (like on a screenshot below).

[image]

Thanks all for reading and helping me!

Here is what I have so far (HTML & CSS):

```
<div id="team" class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="specialheadingtextportfolio">T</h2>
            <div class="specialheadingportfolio"><span class="lightblue">&lt/</span>Team<span class="lightblue">&gt</span></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-12">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-wrap">
                    <a href="#modal-01" title="">
                        <img alt="" src="img/asianwoman.jpg">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                <h5>Jane Doe</h5>
                                <p>Web Designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="teamtext">
                <h3 class="teamtextheading">Jane Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-wrap">
                    <a href="#modal-02" title="">
                        <img alt="" src="img/m2.jpg">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                <h5>Jane Doe</h5>
                                <p>Web Designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="teamtext">
                <h3 class="teamtextheading">Jane Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-wrap">
                    <a href="#modal-03" title="">
                        <img alt="" src="img/girl.jpg">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                <h5>Jane Doe</h5>
                                <p>Web Designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="teamtext">
                <h3 class="teamtextheading">Jane Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <div class="columns portfolio-item">
                <div class="item-wrap">
                    <a href="#modal-04" title="">
                        <img alt="" src="img/beach.jpg">
                        <div class="overlay">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-meta">
                                <h5>Jane Doe</h5>
                                <p>Web Designer</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="link-icon"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="teamtext">
                <h3 class="teamtextheading">Jane Doe</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum... Lorem ipsum...</p>
            </div>
        </div>

   </div>
```

```
#portfolio-wrapper .columns {
margin-bottom: 36px;
}
.portfolio-item .item-wrap {
   height: 450px;
   width: auto;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;

   -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
   transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.portfolio-item .item-wrap a {
   display: block;
   cursor: pointer;
}

/* overlay */
.portfolio-item .item-wrap .overlay {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;

    opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);

   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;

   background: rgba(28, 147, 216, 0.9);
}
.portfolio-item .item-wrap .link-icon {
   display: block;
   color: #fff;
   height: 30px;
   width: 30px;
   font-size: 24px;
   line-height: 30px;
   text-align: center;

   opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);

   -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;

   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -15px;
   margin-top: -15px;
}
.portfolio-item .item-wrap img {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-item-meta { padding: 0px }
.portfolio-item .portfolio-item-meta h5 {
   font-size: 22px;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   font-weight: bold;
   padding-top: 40%;
   color: #fff;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:1600px){
    .portfolio-item .portfolio-item-meta h5 {
        padding-top: 30%;
    }
}
.portfolio-item .portfolio-item-meta p {
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
   color: #eaf2e3;
   margin-bottom: 0;
}

/* on hover */
.portfolio-item:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
.portfolio-item:hover .link-icon {
   opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}

.teamtext{
    background: #464747;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 15px;
    margin-bottom: 70px;
    display: block;
}
.teamtextheading{
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can making relative the image and giving some positions to center the image. The result will be always shown the center of the image and crop the both sides (right and left) if necessary.

```
.portfolio-item .item-wrap img {
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   -ms-transform: translateX(-50%); /** old IE **/
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /** iOS safari ***/
   transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Just need the translate no left or relative positions http://www.bootply.com/IjorBMj3y2

Comment: @Marcos: Thanks a lot! It took you a few seconds only and I was cracking my head with this for few hours... I am feeling ashamed now :( Anyway, you're the hero of the day for me! Haha~ Thanks again it works exactly as I wanted it to work!

Comment: @DaniP yes, but to ensure the image is moved to the left we need the left relative measure before the translate. However, both works fine. Write one more or less property on CSS makes no change on performance or readability.

Comment: @C.Felipe Thank you, you can accept this answer as the correct ones :)

Comment: Sure I will, it says I have to wait for 4 minutes. No problem!

Comment: I tried with no left or relative positions but it didn't work as good as your suggestion...

Comment: It's because I said that  `left` property is to ensure the position of the element before translate with `transform`. `position: relative` is mandatory since you need to room the size of the image. However, position different than static is mandatory for this task. See you soon!

Comment: Thanks for additional clarification! I will for sure remember this. Appreciate your time and help very much. Have great day!